# Numpy in what situation will return "Divide by zero error"?

Tags: python, numpy, zero, divide

I have an expression as below, where as **data** is a matrix and **theta** is a vector, python constantly raise divide by 0 error.
But the only denominator is (1+e^x), every element in this matrix cannot be 0 anyway

```
np.sum(-data[:,-1]*np.log(1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-np.dot(data[:,:-1],theta.transpose())))))
```

Is there any occasion I've ignored that will generate this error?

Weird thing is, the program runs well and results is right even with this error showed every time.

Comment: Is it possible that either `theta` or  `data[:,:-1]` contains complex numbers? (Unlikely since this looks like a manual implementation of logistic regression, but maybe?)

Comment: It shouldn't come about from an errant large negative number either, since `np.log(0)` gives `inf` and doesn't raise the divide-by-zero error. Can you print a small portion of what the data in `theta` and `data[:, :-1]` looks like?

Comment: `np.log(0)` gives the warning `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` and returns `-inf` (using numpy 1.9.1).

Comment: I've tested that, their format is float64, should this be a matter?

Comment: You say "raise divide by 0 error", but then you say the program runs well.  Is the error message actually a warning?  What is the complete, exact text of the error message?

Comment: "data" is a sample of size 5000, each of it is a 20X20 matrix stores greyscale value, I am using gradient descent for logistics regression, initial value for theta is np.ones().

Comment: py:21: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  return (np.sum(-data[:,-1]*np.log(1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-np.dot(data[:,:-1],theta.transpose()))))-(1-data[:,-1])*np.log(1-1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-np.dot(data[:,:-1],theta.transpose())))))+np.sum(theta[1:]**2)*lamda/2.0)*1.0/data.shape[0]

Comment: yes it's actually a warning...sorry for misuse of terms...

Comment: That's the warning you'll get when you compute `np.log(0)`.

Comment: I see now, the warning is all about np.log(0).It's weird what's in log is 1.0/(1.0+e^x), how should this function return 0...

Comment: I saw what the problem is, e^x sometimes goes to a large value and overflow happens...causing the value within the log to be 0! Thanks guys for pointing out those things, they really helped me in understanding this.

Comment: The warning message in your previous comment also shows `np.log(1-1.0/(1.0+np.exp(...)))`.  If the value in `...` is negative with a large magnitude, then `1.0+np.exp(...)` could equal 1.0, and the argument of `np.log` will be 0.

Comment: yeah, that's another potential warning I neglected, thanks so much! A side question: do I need to mark this as "Answered" or it's automatic? I didn't see any button like this.

Comment: I put my comments in an answer.  If they solved the problem for you, feel free to accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message given in the comments to the question:

```
py:21: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log return (np.sum(-data[:,-1]*np.log(1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-np.dot(data[:,:-1],theta.transpose()‌​))))-(1-data[:,-1])*np.log(1-1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-np.dot(data[:,:-1],theta.transpose(‌​))))))+np.sum(theta[1:]**2)*lamda/2.0)*1.0/data.shape[0]
```

it appears that you are computing `np.log(0)`.  E.g.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.log(0)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
-inf
>>>
```

And that is likely happening because `np.exp(...)` is overflowing, or `1.0 + np.exp(...)` is returning 1.0 (because `np.exp(...)` is smaller than the "machine epsilon") and you are computing `np.log(1.0 - 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(...)))`.